# Making all words starting with "@" and "#" clickable

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a project that allows users click on words that start with "#" and "@" i managed to get the one for hashtag working but when i try to implement both at the same time there's a problem

I used regular expression operations to return the value and mark_safe because its an html tag

In the template tag_files i did this

```
def create_hashtag_link(tag):
    url = "/hash/?hash={}".format(tag)
    # or: url = reverse("hashtag", args=(tag,))
    return '<a href="{}">#{}</a>'.format(url, tag)


@register.filter()
def hashtag_links(value):
    return mark_safe(
        re.sub(r"#(\w+)", lambda m: create_hashtag_link(m.group(1)),
               escape(value)))


def create_mention_link(mention):
    link = "/mention/?user={}".format(mention)
    return '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(link, mention)


@register.filter()
def mention_link(value):
    return mark_safe(
        re.sub(r"@(\w+)", lambda x: create_mention_link(x.group(0)),
               escape(value)))
```

In the template i did this

```
{{ post.content|truncatewords:"19"|mention_link|hashtag_links }}
```

It outputs this:

```
#testing things out <a href="/mention/?user=lol">lol</a>
```

hashtag work but "@" doesn't

Comment: What is your input (`post.content`)?

Comment: @Selcuk I'm not sure what you mean, the post.content is a field that contains the post content

Comment: What is the contents of that variable? Can you post an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `#testing things out <a href="/mention/?user=lol">lol</a>`

Isn't this correct? The link looks like the desired result?

Unless it's rendering the above literally

---

---

Try this instead

```
def create_hashtag_link(tag):
    url = "/hash/?hash={}".format(tag)
    # or: url = reverse("hashtag", args=(tag,))
    return '<a href="{}">#{}</a>'.format(url, tag)


@register.filter()
def hashtag_links(value):
    return mark_safe(
        re.sub(r"#(\w+)", lambda m: create_hashtag_link(m.group(1)),
               value))


def create_mention_link(mention):
    link = "/mention/?user={}".format(mention)
    return '<a href="{}">{}</a>'.format(link, mention)


@register.filter()
def mention_link(value):
    return mark_safe(
        re.sub(r"@(\w+)", lambda x: create_mention_link(x.group(0)),
               value))
```

Basically, `escape` does the following ([source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.escape))

> Returns the given text with ampersands, quotes and angle brackets
>   encoded for use in HTML.

I think that once you apply one of the filters, since you do `escape(value)` you have now escaped the whole entire content except the part you substituted. When you apply the second filter, this process repeats, you replace some part, but the untouched section is now escaped. I suspect the final result (if you did a page source) would look like this:

`<a href="/hash/?hash=testing">#testing</a> things out &lt;a href=&quot;/mention/?user=@lol&quot;&gt;@lol&lt;/a&gt;`

So the hashtag (because it was applied last) is ok but the link isn't actually rendering as html.

Comment: It doesn't seem to convert `#testing` into a link.

Comment: ah, ok, got confused by  >hashtag work but "@" doesn't

Comment: it renders #testing things out <a href="/mention/?user=lol">lol</a> literally and 'safe' filter isnt working

Comment: @Akindele OK, in this case, try removing the `escape` function calls

Comment: it worked, thanks, can you explain how you knew its was the escape function?

Comment: Sure, added some thoughts.